# Certificate renewal in Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, certificate, cloudflare, lets-encrypt, google-cloud-run

I am using a LetsEncrypt certificate between Cloudflare and a Cloud Run service and the issuing process is using HTTP-01 challenge, e.g http:///.well-known/acme-challenge/.

The certificate is set to expire in 3 months. Will it renew automatically? What is time timeframe before expiration that it renews?

Comment: Can you talk more about how you have done this?

Comment: Is the SSL certificate self-managed or Cloudflare managed? To quote Cloudflare: Manually configuring SSL requires several steps, and a misconfiguration can prevent users from getting to your website. Cloudflare allows any Internet property to become HTTPS-enabled with the click of a button. You’ll never need to worry about SSL certificates expiring or staying up to date with the latest SSL vulnerabilities when you’re using Cloudflare SSL. https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/